# Why are passed values in a batch %variable% not applied correctly?

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables

[Original Title: Why are lowercase values in a batch %variable% being returned as uppercase?]

#### Condition

I have a batch file where the value is declared for a variable as such:

`SET myVar="something.lowercase"`

But later in the script when you reference that variable as such:

`%myVar%`

<strike>the value is coming in as `SOMETHING.LOWERCASE`</strike> which is causing the particular command to not work correctly. (**see resolution:** *the issue was a spurious `"` in the command and the uppercase was the way the "failure" was being reported*)

#### Concern

<strike>Why and under what situation does this happen?</strike> **moot** *as the value is not being changed, but rather the way the failure is reported and the failure was due to a `"` being introduced in the passed value* (**see resolution**)

#### Context

For context, <strike>in case it matters</strike>, it is being called in this way: (*it turned out to matter as the introduced `"` was causing the check to fail and the confusion was coming from the "cannot find ..." being uppercase*)

`TASKLIST /FI "IMAGENAME eq %myVar%" 2>NUL | FIND /I /N "%myVar%">NUL`

I suspect that this is somehow happening in the context of this command, but cannot be sure and don't know why. If that is by chance the case, how can I mitigate it? (**see resolution**)

Thank you in advance.

---

#### Resolution

Thanks to @Campo's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50009799/why-are-lowercase-values-in-a-batch-variable-being-returned-as-uppercase?#comment87038205_50009799), changing the value by dropping the `"` resolved the issue and the script functions correctly now. Thank you.

Comment: If you can answer the question "under what situation does this happen?", preferably with an MCVE (minimal, complete verifiable example), I'm sure someone will be able to answer the question "why"?

Comment: I am going to assume the image name is in uppercase. Which should not matter with the command you are using because you are telling it to ignore casing with the `FIND` command.  Even the `imagename` option with the `TASKLIST` command doesn't care about casing.  So I am not understanding what your problem is.  The code you chose to share works perfectly.

Comment: @Joe I'd be happy to but I am not 100% clear on what you mean, if you can please clarify, I will happily provide any additional information that might assist. The question is simply asking under what circumstances a variable value is capitalized, this to me doens't seem to need an example per se, just existing "behavior" and why and when those are asserted. Am I missing something? I also added that it happens in that command I provided, so I don't see what else I can provide but I would be happy to if you can clarify what more is needed.

Comment: @Squashman That's what I thought as well but for some reason if you are looking for `notepad.exe` (hard coded) it works fine but if it gets converted to `NOTEPAD.EXE` (passed) which is the case above, then it doesn't, hence why I was a bit thrown and reached out.

Comment: @GµårÐïåñ - the example you provide redirects output to NUL, so it's not very clear why you think it's changing the case of an environment variable (it probably isn't, more likely there's something else happening in your batch file that you're misinterpreting)

Comment: If you have `SET myVar="something.lowercase"`, then unless you later `Set` `myVar`, it can't change. The output from `Find`, _which is taken from the  `TaskList` command_, isn't your variable, `%myVar%`, it is just a string. Your issue is probably because you're needlessly including doublequotes in your variable value, it should be, `Set "myVar=something.lowercase"`. Because you've included the doublequotes the `TaskList` filter is looking for `"IMAGENAME eq "something.lowercase""` and your `Find` command is trying to match `""something.lowercase""`.

Comment: Compo is right. Run it with `echo on` and analyze the output: your variable *is* in lowercase.

Comment: @Joe the `>NUL` is to keep the display on the screen, and has nothing to do with the issue as replacing it without use of the variable works fine as intended. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @Compo No, it is set only once and it is not set or changed later (by me I mean) and I wasn't aware that formatting as a string (aka using the quote) is a problem, but you are right in that it will probably introduce the spurious quotes in the mix of things, but I wasn't aware that would change the value to uppercase; but I can change that and see what difference it will make. I appreciate your thoughts and will test that. I have a feeling that oversight might be my issue, so thank you.

Comment: Again: your variable does NOT change, it stays lowercase.It's the output of `tasklist`, which is uppercase and filtered by `find /i` (see `find /?` if you are not 100% sure,  what `/i` does). Simple example: `echo HELLO  | find /i "hello"`)

Comment: @GµårÐïåñ, it doesn't change the variable, you are mistaken! If you want to verify that, just add `Set myVar` several times throughout your code. When you run the code it will output both the variable name and value which should verify matters.

Comment: To summarize: the premise in the question is incorrect - the value in `myVar` isn't being converted to uppercase. What is happening is that `myVar` contains characters that the OP didn't expect it to contain.  Those characters happen to be double-quotes due to cmd.exe's bizarre quote handling.

Comment: Another way to see what's going on is to put `@echo on`/`@echo off` around the `TASKLIST /FI ...` command, and you'll see exactly how the command is interpreting the `myVar` variable.

Comment: Stephan, MichaelBurr, et al -  yes it is moot now, as already updated and stated above the `"` was the issue, there is no reason to keep harping on that. The premise of the question was based on observation of the returned value from the command fail showing uppercase value, it was a fair assumption and hence the whole point of asking for insight of the others. Compo properly answered and figured it out (without attitude), I immediately acknowledged it and updated the question, so what's the issue here? Just pounding on something after the fact and without providing actual resolution is noise.

Comment: @Stephan yes because the issue was properly diagnosed, already addressed and acknowledged, so why the need to repeat it when it adds no additional value and just rehashes the already reached conclusion with unnecessary comments that adds no additional value? See what I mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is because you're needlessly including doublequotes in your variable value.

Because you've included the doublequotes the `TaskList` filter is looking for:

```bat
"IMAGENAME eq "something.lowercase""
```

...and your `Find` command is trying to match:

```bat
""something.lowercase""
```

The fix is to use the correct syntax for setting a variable:

```bat
Set "myVar=something.lowercase"
```

Comment: I was hoping you would make an answer so I can properly accept, but in the meantime I had linked your comment for clarity. Thank you again. The spurious `"` was indeed the issue and you caught that, thank you again.